# Параллельное выполнение асинхронных задач C#

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Имеется button1, при нажатии на который должна запуститься параллельная обработка файлов.
Код:

```
    private async void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count; i++)
            {
                    await Processing(paths[i]);
            }
    }
```

Сам метод:

```
public async Task Processing(string path)
    {
        byte[] newFile; //Переменная для записи нового файла
        using (FileStream f = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            byte[] openFile = new byte[f.Length];
            await f.ReadAsync(openFile, 0, openFile.Length);
            //Обработка файла, в ней же и записываются значения в newFile
        }
        File.Delete(path); //Можно вместо этого изменить FileMode в следующей строке, но пока что не до этого
        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await f.WriteAsync(newFile, 0, newFile.Length);
        }
        processed++;
        label10.Text = "Обработано файлов: " + processed;
    }
```

Обрабатывает несколько файлов и сохраняет пустые файлы. Ощущение, что файлы читаются неправильно, либо неправильно записываются. Ошибка в том, что делаю методы параллельно или в асинхронности самих методов? Спасибо.

Comment: 1) Этот код обрабатыевает файлы последовательно. 2) Этот код показан как есть? Не вижу в нем смысла, он берет содержимое файла, читает и его же без каких-либо изменений зарисывает обратно. 3) Параллельно обрабатывать файлы смысла мало, так как диск будет все равно данные выдавать для N файлов с такой же скоростью как и для одного файла. 4) Грубых ошибок в коде не вижу, ну если только я бы написал это всё вместе в 3-4 строки кода. 5) Используется массив - либо файлы очень маленькие, либо вам стоит освоить работу с потоками данных через буфер, а не вычитывать полностью в память.

Comment: `byte[] openFile = new byte[f.Length];` -> `newFile = new byte[f.Length];` ?

Comment: @tym32167 точняк, проглядел. :)

Comment: @aepot `1) Этот код обрабатыевает файлы последовательно.` - таки асинхронно, но не параллельно. П.С. Хотел докопаться, перечитал, а ты таки написал тоже верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, как указали на ошибку, вы читаете файл в массив `openFile`, а записываете массив `newFile`, а в нём пусто.

Во-вторых, вот то же самое, только код короче. С выносом обработки данных в отдельный поток, чтобы не вешать приложение. Допустим, обработка данных выполняется ощутимо долго. Допустим, количество байт в записываемом файле такое же, как в прочитанном.

```cs
private async Task ProcessFileAsync(string path)
{
    byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);
    await Task.Run(() => ProcessData(bytes));
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, bytes);
    processed++;
    label10.Text = "Обработано файлов: " + processed;
}

private void ProcessData(byte[] bytes)
{
    // здесь синхронная обработка данных массива с записью изменений в этот же массив
}
```

В-третьих, обработка файлов происходит последовательно, один за другим. Можно сделать параллельно, но это имеет смысл только если чтение и запись файла занимают немного времени по сравнению с обработкой данных.

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[paths.Count]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = ProcessFileAsync(paths[i]);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Вот теперь обработка полностью будет выполняться действительно параллельно.

Кстати, суффикс `...Async` стоит дописывать только к ожидабельным (awaitable) методам, то есть к которым можно применить `await`. Методы типа `async void` ожидать нельзя, как следствие и нельзя их признать асинхронными из вызывающего кода.

Comment: aepot - я просто пришел в Ваш ответ аплодировать стоя! Коротко, ёмко и правильно!

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(paths.Select(p=>ProcessFileAsync(p)));` ?

Comment: @tym32167 ага, но я решил в Linq глубоко не залезать, и без того материал сложный.

Comment: okay, так тоже норм

Comment: `но это имеет смысл только если чтение и запись файла занимают немного времени` - и немного памяти :)

Comment: @tym32167 прямая корреляция :) ну если не углубляться в HDD vs SSD. :)

Comment: @tym32167 а еще `File.***Async` - багованное API, исправленное только в .NET 6. Если файлов очень много, форму все равно будет слегка подвешивать. Будет заметно, если там будет крутиться какая-то анимация например.

Comment: @aepot, Благодарю Вас. Всё заработало как надо, а свои ошибки я понял. Размер исходного файла от получившегося отличается, поэтому приходится записывать файл по новой.

Comment: @aepot , а можете пожалуйста уточнить, про какой буфер идет речь? (В комментарии про то, что я заношу данные в массив)

Comment: @aepot подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать строчку File.WriteAllBytesAsync рабочей. Установил .Net 5.0, .Net Core 3.1, все равно не видит ее VS

Comment: @Varagian нужно целевой фреймворк в настройках проекта поменять на .NET 5. Если у вас .NET Framework 4.x, то проще создать новый проект и аккуратно перенести в него код. Если .NET Core 3.1, то достаточно поменять версию дотнета в настройках проекта. Ну и студия 2019 нужна.

Comment: @Varagian как вариант - создать отдельный Task и в нём уже не File.WriteAllBytesAsync использовать, а File.WriteAllBytes

Comment: @Blackmeser это можно и на .NET 5 сделать.

Comment: @aepot VS 2019, в настройках проекта не появляется .NET 5, хотя установил SDK и установил рантайм для этого фреймворка. Если создавать новый проект, то тоже не появляется ничего

Comment: @Varagian Создайте новый проект по шаблону .NET, а не .NET Framework, вы не тот тип проекта выбираете при создании. Это должно быть настолько просто, что не достойно задания вопросов на SO :)

Comment: @aepot вот именно, что должно быть, а по факту всё идет не так, как надо...

Comment: @aepot все получилось, спасибо)

Comment: @Varagian ура, а то я уже скриншот приготовил https://i.imgur.com/NbKiP4l.png

Comment: @aepot Добрый вы человек :)